# Can't get rid of non-capturing regex groups

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex

I have the following string:

```
In order to take this course, you must:<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have access to a computer.<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have continuous broadband Internet access.<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have the ability/permission to install plug-ins (e.g. Adobe Reader or Flash) and software.<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have the ability to download and save files and documents to a computer.<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have the ability to open Microsoft file and documents (.doc, .ppt, .xls, etc.).<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Be competent in the English language.<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have access to a relational database management system.&nbsp; A good open-source option is MySQL (<a href="http://dev.mysql.com" target="_blank">dev.mysql.com</a>).<br>
<br>
&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have completed the Discrete Structures course.<br>
<br>
&radic;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Have read the Student Handbook.
```

I'm trying to select the text in the middle (excluding the title, encoded spaces and `<br>`s), for instance, the first match should be: `Have access to a computer.`

I've tried the following two, but can't make it work.

This one selects the entire line: `^(?:&radic;([(&nbsp;)|\s]*))(.*)(?:(\<br\\?\>)*)$`, I tried to call `Regex.Matches(requirements.InnerHtml, RequirementsExtractorRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline)[0].Captures[0].Value`, and here is the value: `&radic; &nbsp; &nbsp;Have access to a computer.<br>`.

And this one doesn't select anything: `^(?<=&radic;([(&nbsp;)|\s]*))(.*)(?=(\<br\\?\>)*)$`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean, what are you doing wrong in addition to using regular expressions to parse HTML? Surely, you've seen "[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight modification of the regex produces (almost, See below) the desired result

```
^(?:&radic;(?:&nbsp;|\s)*)(.*)(?:<br/?>)
```

Reference the target match in group #1

```
Regex.Matches(requirements.InnerHtml, RequirementsExtractorRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline)[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Tested on [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) with multiline match option on.

***Caveat***

The regex matches all targeted occurrences but the last, due to the non-optional br element. Quantifying that part includes the last occurrence in the matches but makes the capture group #1 contain the br element terminating the line - the greedy universal match overrides. Adding the line termination anchor prevents a match (though it shouldn't in my understanding of the specs - perhaps an artifact of the testing environment ?).

Comment: It doesn't match on the last statement. I thought that `(?:&nbsp;|\s)*` stands for *either `&nbsp` or a whitespace, zero or more times, order doesn't matter*, isn't that so? What is then used to look for a choice of optional **words** repeated zero or more times?

Comment: Both of your observations are correct and you got your syntax right. Imho the problem is not the second non-capturing groupbut  the third one: As ist stands, it prevents matching of the last line; when qulaifying with `*`, the preceding greedy capturing group wins out in every match (ie. incudes `<br>`). I have no solution to this one (other than artifically appending a `<br>\n` to the original string).

Comment: I tried to change the dot, but still doesn't work, see [this](http://regexr.com/3ags1) one.

Comment: The ampersands of the html entities haven't made it into the regexr pattern line and you have to include at least the `.` in your character class. If you do so and take `.` as a stand in for the ampersand, you get `^(?:.radic;(?:.nbsp;|\s)*)([A-Za-z0-9.\s]*)(?:<br\/?>)` which matches 4 times.

Comment: I ended up using my original query, excluding the final group, and replacing it manually from each resulting match.